# how to make reflection doesn't affect the environment? (cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color, glass, reflection

The environment light is white, however, the reflection on the glass is translucent blue.
and the glass it self is transparent.

I tried to change the environment into other colors, or change the glass color

But all failed, I can't make it like this:

How can I reach this?

[image]

I'm using cycles and my blender version is 4.0

Comment: is it possible to share your file or more info? This is truly hard to tell from 1 image